# How to configure a DNS server by YAST2

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-zone, opensuse, sles

I run these commands to install DNS server dependencies on openSUSE Tumbleweed:

```
sudo zypper in -t pattern dhcp_dns_server
sudo systemctl enable named.service
sudo systemctl start named.service
```

To configure the DNS server, I'm trying YAST2 following [this documentation](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/reference/html/book-opensuse-reference/cha-dns.html):

```
sudo yast2 dns-server
```

I intend to configure `example.com` domain zone with IP address `1.2.3.4`.

#### What I did

I have a DNS zone of *master* type:

[image: Zone: master]

My *NS Records* tab is:

[image: NS Records tab]

My *Records* tab is:

[image: Records tab]

#### Problem

However, saving the configuration runs into a problem:

> Warning
>
> Saving the configuration failed. Change the settings?

[image: Problem]

I couldn't figure it out. Can anyone help?

### Update

Suggested by @JiriB I ran these commands and reconfigured the DNS server. But the observation is the same as before:

```
sudo systemctl revert named.service
sudo rpm  -qV bind
sudo cp /etc/named.conf.YaST-backup /etc/named.conf
sudo yast2 dns-server
```

Comment: Why do you start and enable named manually. Shouldn't YAST take care about it? I would start `systemctl revert named.service`, `rpm  -qV bind`, then i would restore `/etc/named.conf.YaST-backup`, and start with `yast dns-server` again.

Comment: @JiriB Thanks =) Let me try!

Comment: @JiriB It didn't work! Updated the post!

Comment: Then you must reveal more info.

Comment: @JiriB Right! The steps in the post are all I do. Let me see if I can provide more info =)

Comment: I just found that Tumbleweed dropped the dns and dhcp modules from Yast one year ago. https://lists.opensuse.org/archives/list/factory@lists.opensuse.org/thread/BPGEJPUAYVYW7DGZKEMDPFZLE3OSEEBB/ (I finally got a home server and had some frustration because even Suse's own documentation only described the nonexistent modules as "the" way to configure these services.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem of:

> Warning
>
> Saving the configuration failed. Change the settings?

Got resolved by stopping the `named` service before launching YAST2:

```
sudo systemctl stop named.service
```